# join table with limit in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Each user may have more than 1 address. I would like to limit users and extract all addresses by user_id.

```
user_ids = session.query(User.user_id).limit(10).all()

address_ids = session.query(Address).filter(Address.user_id.in_(user_ids)).all()
```

How can I do it in one query?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use subquery.

```
sub_query = session.query(User.user_id).limit(10).subquery()
address_ids = session.query(Address).filter(Address.user_id.in_(sub_query)).all()
```

Comment: Thank you. It's better than my approach

Comment: Thank you so much.